# Get a sample IP addess from location (reverse lookup)

Tags: geolocation, ip-address, ip-geolocation

I'm using a service that gets user's location from an IP address I provide. I was doing it a wrong way for a while, so now I would like to backfill the users' location. But all I have is their location (in coordinates) in my DB, so I need a way to get a sample IP from that location.
Any advice on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the coordinates, you can find the nearest city based on the coordinates. There is no need to reverse to get estimated IP address.

Comment: So I can estimate an IP from the city? How?

Comment: Maybe I don't get your question. You want to find IP address or city?